# RPM weak dependencies

Tags: c++, compilation, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

In my RPM spec file I have declared that my software package requires a C++ compiler to build:

```
BuildRequires: gcc-c++
```

Now I want to make it possible to build this package using devtoolset-8 (or even clang in the future). How can I make the dependency resolver to fail if none of `gcc-c++` nor `devtoolset-8` have found? I am looking for some sort of `OR` requirements:

```
BuildRequires: ( gcc-c++ || devtoolset-8 ) # ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RPM > 4.13 has support for boolean dependencies.
You can just give,

```
BuildRequires: (gcc-c++ or devtoolset-8)
```

It's documented here,
https://rpm.org/user_doc/boolean_dependencies.html

Comment: Although it's not recommended, if both packages have a common file, say /usr/bin/X, you could specify that in the requires as a workaround.